# Date range validation with jQuery date pickers with a custom format

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to disable the automatic filling of the "to" date as per the "from" date selection to make a validation. By default it is taking the "to" date in *mm-dd-yy* format, but I want it to be *dd-mm-yy*.

I have tried the following but it is not working.

```
$(function () {
  $("#fromDate").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    buttonImage: "resources/images/calender.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate:'01-08-2013',
    maxDate:"${preDate}",
    onSelect: function (selected) {
      var dt = new Date(selected);
      dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
      $("#toDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
    }
  });
  $("#toDate").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    buttonImage: "resources/images/calender.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate:new Date(spltDate[2],spltDate[1]-1,spltDate[0]),
    maxDate:"${preDate}",
    onSelect: function (selected) {
      var dt = new Date(selected);
      dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
      $("#fromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
    }
  });
});
```

How can I change the date format?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try using -
$("#fromDate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", 'dd-mm-yy');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have another JS or something break format